# Regex in preg_replace to detect url format and extract elements

Tags: php, regex, url

I need to replace certain user-entered URLs with embedded flash objects...and I'm having trouble with a regex that I'm using to match the url...I think mainly because the URLs are SEO-friendly and therefore a bit more difficult to parse

```
URL structure: http://www.site.com/item/item_title_that_can_include_1('_etc-32CHARACTERALPHANUMERICGUID
```

I need to both detect a match of an URL in that format and capture the  32CHARACTERALPHANUMERICGUID which is always placed after the - in the url

something like this:

```
$ret = preg_replace('#http://www\.site\.com/item/([^-])-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#','<embed>itemid=$2</embed>', $ret);
```

For some reason, the above does not find a match for an URL in the specified format.  I'm new to regexes, so I think I'm missing something fairly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Examine the results - it was made for parsing URLs. You'll be able to extract the data you require from the tokens returned.

If you are regex crazy, try this...

```
/^http:\/\/www\.site\.com\/item\/[^-]*\-([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})$/
```

Your example is almost there, *but*...

- When you do the not character range, i.e. `[^-]`, you still need a quantifier. I placed `*`, or *0 or more*.
- You don't seem to use the *item title*, so we won't bother capturing it.
- You should use beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors if the string is always exactly like that.
- You say the GUID is 32 chars, so we may as well explicitly state that with the `{32}` quantifier.